# Making elements stretch horizontally in a QScrollArea in PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qscrollarea

I'm using `Python 3.5` and `PyQT5` and trying to create a window with a list of graphs(using `matplotlib`). There are enough graphs that the window will need to scroll vertically.

Using `QScrollArea` it locks the graph sizes in both directions then just scrolls if the window becomes smaller, which leads to whitespace to the right in my use case most times.  Just using a normal `QWidget`based window lets the graph stretch to fit.

Ideally, I'd like to find a way to let the graphs naturally stretch horizontally to fill space, and remain fixed vertically to enable scrolling.

Here is some simplified code which renders one window with stretching behaviour, and another with the `QScrollArea` object which stretches in neither direction.

```
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QScrollArea, QGridLayout, QSizePolicy


class SimpleGraph(FigureCanvas):
    """Canvas class, which acts as QWidget and renders a sin wave"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=2, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        self.axes.hold(False)

        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)


class NormalWindow(QWidget):
    """Normal window based on Qwidget"""

    def __init__(self, width=480, height=320, title="Normal Window", *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMinimumSize(width, height)
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.show()

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(SimpleGraph())
        grid.addWidget(SimpleGraph())
        grid.addWidget(SimpleGraph())

        self.setLayout(grid)


class ScrollWindow(QScrollArea):
    """Simple window based on QScrollArea"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        graph_list = QWidget()
        grid = QGridLayout()

        grid.addWidget(SimpleGraph())
        grid.addWidget(SimpleGraph())

        graph_list.setLayout(grid)

        self.setWidget(graph_list)

        self.setWindowTitle('Scroll Window')
        self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = NormalWindow()
window2 = ScrollWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```